# Data cleaning loop in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns that need I to clean. All columns need to be cleaned with the same logic. I can do this for as many variables as I have

```
dsr$DSR23 <- ifelse(dsr$DSR23 == 'Refused', NA, dsr$DSR23)
dsr$DSR24 <- ifelse(dsr$DSR24 == 'Refused', NA, dsr$DSR24)
dsr$DSR25 <- ifelse(dsr$DSR25 == 'Refused', NA, dsr$DSR25)
```

but I would like to do it in one for-loop, if possible.

Can someone come up with the code to do this without copying and pasting the same ifelse statement a million times?

Comment: Have you tried making the for loop? If so, what problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2):

This is a possibly confusing script, but you can consider using the `within` function to execute a `for`-loop local to the dataframe, then storing the result back into the dataframe object. Here's an example:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20, c=sample(0:1,10,TRUE))
d
#    a  b c
#1   1 11 0
#2   2 12 0
#3   3 13 1
#4   4 14 1
#5   5 15 0
#6   6 16 1
#7   7 17 1
#8   8 18 1
#9   9 19 1
#10 10 20 0
d <- within(d, {
    for(i in 1:2) # column numbers you want to recode
        assign(names(d)[i], ifelse(c==1, NA, d[,i]))
    rm(i)
})
d
#    a  b c
#1   1 11 0
#2   2 12 0
#3  NA NA 1
#4  NA NA 1
#5   5 15 0
#6  NA NA 1
#7  NA NA 1
#8  NA NA 1
#9  NA NA 1
#10 10 20 0
```

Basically, this executes the `ifelse` function on each variable, stores those back into the dataframe within the `within` function, then you just have to store the result back into the original dataframe.

Note: I know there are many ways to do this, so I'm just throwing one out. Undoubtedly someone will criticize the use of `assign` here, which is a perfectly valid criticism.

Answer (score 1):

I've used code like this before for cleaning:

```
vars<-c("DSR23", "DSR24", "DSR25")
dsr[,vars] = lapply(vars, function(x) ifelse(dsr[,x]=="Refused", NA, dsr[,x]))
```

In R using apply over a for loop is often preferred

Answer (score 0):

for loops in R are notoriously slow. You could try subsetting your dataframe. If your example works on the basis of: if the slot equals 'Refused' then change the entry to NA, then:

```
dsr$DSR23[dsr$DSR23 == 'Refused'] <- NA
```